# Setting up sns_publish_operator in airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

Has anyone used the sns_publish_operator?

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/sns_publish_operator.html

I am quite new to airflow and am having some issues around setting up the architecture correctly.

I have set up a simple DAG with a data quality check task. Basically, if the dataset fails the data quality checks, I'd like to send an SNS notification. If it passes the data quality checks, I'd like it to reframe from sending an email.

There does not seem to be as much online help in this realm as I thought. Any resources or general tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit older, but maybe this helps someone still.

First addressing the SnsPublishOperator: You will need to setup an Airflow connection to AWS. There is multiple ways to do that. The easiest is probably using the Web UI. Go there to Admin->Connections->[+] (add new record). Then you set it up as 'Amazon Webservices Connection' Conn Type. Login and Password are the AWS key and key secret. Finally, you also have to provide the region, where you SNS topic is seated in the 'Extras' section:

```
{"region_name": "us-east-1"}
```

Now, you can use the Operator in you code, by providing it also the new connection's conn_id:

```
my_sns_task = SnsPublishOperator(
    task_id='task_name',
    target_arn='your_sns_topic_arn',
    message='your_message',
    aws_conn_id=conn_id
)
```

Theoretically, that operator also has a "subject" parameter, but I receive an error from the component, when I try to set it.

As for incorporating that operator into your DAG, a possible way would be to have the task, that evaluates your data, fail, if the checks to do not pass, and have the sns task be triggered on failure:

```
my_sns_task = SnsPublishOperator(
    task_id='task_name',
    target_arn='your_sns_topic_arn',
    message='your_message',
    aws_conn_id=conn_id,
    trigger_rule='one_failed'
)

my_sns_task.set_upstream(datacheck_task)
```

Comment: From Airflow UI under connection > Amazon Web Services, what should be host for SnsPublishOperator? @Warner

Comment: @JaySean, I would assume, that the AWS connection would not have/use that field, but I'm not sure. Therefore, I leave that for you to find out, and post here, if you do. ;)